# python3 TypeError: string argument expected, got 'bytes'

Tags: python-3.x

getting the following error on these lines, here is the code:

```
import subprocess    
from io import StringIO

image1, buffer1 = captureTestImage(str(cameraSettings), str(testWidth), str(testHeight))

imageData.write(subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True))
```

getting the following error on these (2) lines above:

```
TypeError: string argument expected, got 'bytes'
```

I've tried `cast`ing the variable values above, but that doesnt seem to resolve the situation.

How are `bytes` being sent instead of a `string` and how can i resolve this?

Thank you

```
** ADDED **
def captureTestImage(settings, width, height):
    command = "raspistill %s -w %s -h %s -t 200 -e bmp -n -o -" % (settings, width, height)
    #imageData = StringIO.StringIO() #only used python2
    imageData = StringIO()
    imageData.write(subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True))
    imageData.seek(0)
    im = Image.open(imageData)
    buffer = im.load()
    imageData.close()
    return im, buffer
```

Comment: what *exactly* causes the exception? what is *captureTestImage*? what is *imageData*?

Comment: @FObersteiner - added additional code

Comment: you seem to be reading a file; you do not want to use string io for that; since you just have bytes, which could be anything. maybe try using [bytes io](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) instead.